# Issue with summing values form joined tables

Tags: sql, database, left-join, inner-join

I have a main table named Jobs. Each job can have multiple levels. Each level can have multiple sub-levels, each sub-level can have multiple tasks. All tasks contain an EstimatedHours column.

Jobs Table:

| JobId | JobName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Job1 |
| 2 | Job2 |

Levels Table:

| LevelId | JobId | LevelName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Job 1 Level 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Job 1 Level 2 |
| 3 | 2 | Job 2 Level 1 |

SubLevels Table:

| SubLevelId | LevelId | SubLevelName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Job 1 Level 1 Sub 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Job 1 Level 1 Sub 2 |
| 3 | 2 | Job 1 Level 2 Sub 1 |
| 4 | 2 | Job 1 Level 2 Sub 2 |
| 5 | 3 | Job 2 Level 1 Sub 1 |

DoorTasks Table:

| TaskId | SubLevelId | TaskName | EstimatedHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Job 1 Door Task 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | Job 1 Door Task 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | Job 1 Door Task 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | Job 1 Door Task 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | Job 2 Door Task 5 | 1 |

DoorFrameTasks Table:

| TaskId | SubLevelId | TaskName | EstimatedHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Job 1 Door Frame Task 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | Job 1 Door Frame Task 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | Job 1 Door Frame Task 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | Job 1 Door Frame Task 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | Job 2 Door Frame Task 5 | 2 |

DoorHardwareTasks Table:

| TaskId | SubLevelId | TaskName | EstimatedHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Job 1 Door Frame Task 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | Job 1 Door Frame Task 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | Job 1 Door Frame Task 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 | Job 2 Door Frame Task 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | Job 2 Door Frame Task 5 | 4 |

My current query is

```
SELECT 
    j.JobName,
    SUM(dt.EstimatedHours) + SUM(df.EstimatedHours) + SUM(dh.EstimatedHours) AS "Total Estimated Hours"
FROM  
    Jobs AS j 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Levels AS l ON l.JobId = j.JobId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    SubLevels AS sl ON sl.LevelId = l.LevelId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    DoorTasks AS dt ON dt.SubLevelId = sl.SubLevelId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    DoorFrameTasks AS df ON df.SubLevelId = sl.SubLevelId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    DoorHardwareTasks AS dh ON dh.SubLevelId = sl.SubLevelId         
GROUP BY
    j.JobName
```

I need a query that will sum all Estimated hours for each job and display the JobName and Total EstimatedHours.  You can see an example of the table structures and my current query [HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36ZuBDWpDMowcs5wbMQZxK/3).  My problem is, some of the tasks' estimated hours are being added multiple times.

Comment: Dr, df, and she can have multiple rows for a given sublevel Id; you can't join them together, you have to build three separate  subqueries, each summarising one of those tables by jobid, then you can join them together by job_id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with t as 
          (
           select sublevelid, estimatedhours
           from   DoorHardwareTasks
           union all
           select sublevelid, estimatedhours
           from   DoorFrameTasks
           union all 
           select sublevelid, estimatedhours
           from   DoorTasks
          )

select   jobid 
        ,jobname
        ,sum(estimatedhours)
from   t join SubLevels using(sublevelid) 
         join Levels    using(levelid) 
         join Jobs      using(jobid)
group by jobid, jobname
```

| jobid | jobname | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Job 1 | 55 |
| 2 | Job 2 | 10 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=adc51bfcf810cd5ac2dbc96f5a08ede5&hide=1)